# Presetting a parameter in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically a user is  on a project page where they click add new website, which is set out like this

```
<%= link_to 'Add Asset', new_website_path(:project_id => "#{@project.id}" ), class: 'btn btn-md btn-danger' %>
```

and then they fill out a form with some data. However I want it so that when they submit that form, that the project id (from the project page they were just on) gets saved under the project_id variable of the website but for some reason this isn't working.

```
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @website = Website.new(:type => 'Website', :project_id => @project)
  end

  def create
    @website = current_user.assets.build(website_params)

    if @website.save
      flash[:notice] = "Asset successfully added."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'projects', :action => 'show', :id => @website.project_id)
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  private

  def website_params
    params.require(:website).permit(:id, :type,:url, :page_rank, :rev_company ,:social_pages)
  end
end
```

Is there something missing as to why this isn't working? When I check in the console, all the websites I add have a project_id of nil.

When i go onto the form in my browser this is the address:

```
http://localhost:3000/websites/new?project_id=1
```

Also, I think it is getting the right project ID because in the form I have a condition which looks at that project ID to see if it is of type website as in:

```
#views/websites/new.html.erb
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default newasset">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title ptd"><%= "New #{@project.type}" %></h3>
        </div>
<div class='panel-body'>
            <div class='form group'>
<%= simple_form_for(@website, html: {class: 'form-group' }) do |f| %>
<% if (@project.type == 'Website') %>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-3">
  <%= f.input :title, label: 'Website Name' %>
  <%= f.input :url %>
  <%= f.input :rev_company, label: "Revenue Company" %>
  <%= f.input :social_pages, label: "Number of Social Sites" %>
  <%= f.input :page_rank %><br />
  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
<% else %>
You should not see this
<% end %>
<% end %>


        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are passing `:project_id` correctly then all you need to permit `project_id` in `website_params` method.

```
def website_params
  params.require(:website).permit(:id, :project_id, :type,:url, :page_rank, :rev_company ,:social_pages)
  ##                                     ^
  ##                                     Permit project_id 
end
```

Currently, you have not permitted the field `project_id` which is why its not getting saved.

For **Rails 4+ (with Strong Parameters)** you need to *explicitly* specify the fields which you would like to save in database.

Comment: ahh ok this makes sense. My only concern was that I did have it like this originally but someone told me to take it out because it can allow people to inject a different project_id there if they wanted? Is this right or am I stil protected this way

Comment: I tried adding this way but it still was not adding it to the website. I updated my question to include the browser request to make sure that I am passing project_id correctly.

Comment: That's because you are passing `project_id` as query params so its accessible as `params[:project_id]` and NOT `params[:website][:project_id]`.

Comment: so your saying i should be passing it as params[:project_id]? Isn't that how I have it or are you saying to pass it as params[:website][:project_id]. Sorry for the dumb questions but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Pass it as `params[:website][:project_id]` is what I am saying.   Also, unless you don't set the value of project_id, it will always be nil. If you pass it as `params[:website][:project_id]` then `website_params` method would take care of it being saved correctly. You can take a look at [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), even that would be a better approach for you.

Comment: Hey when i try that i get this error `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` I was considering using nested attributes but as it currently stands the website model inherits from the asset model which is the one with all these attributes and the website model just grabs which ever ones it needs from the asset model.

Comment: Like I said, you need to pass project_id as `params[:website][:project_id]`, currently you are passing it as `params[:project_id]`. So obviously, accessing `params[:website][:project_id]` would result in error as it does not exist right now. Also, take a look at nested resources link that I provided in previous comment.

Comment: So i tried this (if this is what you mean) `<%= link_to 'Add Asset', new_website_path(:website => { :project_id => @project.id }), class: 'btn btn-md btn-danger' %>` and have the [:website][:project_id] in the controller but it is still not saving to the id. I had a look at the nested resources but I don't think thats what I want to do, because I am not trying to access any attributes of nested resources..if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

@project is an object, and the database must be expecting an integer.
You should call:

```
@project.id
```

The best solution anyway is to do:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]
  @website = @project.websites.build(:type => 'Website')
end
```

To allow rails to do his magick association through the models if you have declared the: belongs, and has_one/many

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Which method do I put this in? the new or create method? Also will this create a new project every time I want to build an asset? Because I only want it to create new websites and add them to the existing project

Comment: This is for the new method. The create method will need to change id, for project_id as stated in the other answer.